# mysql delete syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete multiple rows from multiple tables having the same condition but will always return syntax error.

This is the code:

```
DELETE FROM table1,table2,table3
WHERE guid = 'CE4EF453-937F-C7F9-7AE429VB0128'
```

The error code is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'WHERE guid = 'CE4EF453-937F-C7F9-7AE429VB0128'' at line 2

Comment: See multi-table delete in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing INNER JOINs. Something like **the following** perhaps.

```
DELETE FROM table1,table2,table3
USING table1 INNER JOIN table2 INNER JOIN table3
WHERE table1.guid = 'CE4EF453-937F-C7F9-7AE429VB0128'
    AND table2.guid  = table1.guid 
    AND table3.guid = table1.guid
```

**[(Reference)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a shot:

```
DELETE FROM table1,table2,table3
WHERE table1.guid = 'CE4EF453-937F-C7F9-7AE429VB0128'
  AND table1.guid = table2.guid
  AND table1.guid = table3.guid
```